# Trying to programmatically set value of a list item's URL column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm trying to add a list item that contains a URL in its second column and I keep getting the following error:

> Execution failed: The anchor tag supplied for the List Item was not
>   properly formed. (line 131, file "Code")

The lines in question (130 and 131) ares:

```
var values = [a,"< a href=\'DEBUG\'>details</a>",c,d,e,f,g,h];
var thislistitem = kbPage.addListItem(values);
```

I've tried passing the following for the second variable:

- `""`
- `"<a href=\'DEBUG\'>details</a>"`
- `DEBUG`
- `http://www.something.com/`

And I keep getting the same error. I expect that I should be passing a pair of values (a label and a url) somehow instead of a simple string, but I can find no reference anywhere to how to do that.

Comment: The title has `setValueByIndex`, but it's not mentioned in your question.

Comment: @sandwich D'uh, you are right and I just fixed it. I was typing the question and working on  the code simultaneously, and that was an artificat from a prior iteration. Problem persists with the modified code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all there are three things:-

1. Coloumn in which want to enter the  tag should be of URL type
2. Anchor tag should not have escape characters in between instead of
       this `"<a href=\'DEBUG\'>details</a>"` 
   use `"<a href='DEBUG'>details</a>"`
3. Biggest mistake was **space** `< a` between **<** and **a** makes anchor tag invalid

Apply these things and it wont show any error